# Cassandra Read Timeout when 1 node is down out of 3 nodes in a cluster

Tags: cassandra

We have 3 node cluster with Replication factor 3. During Writes, data is inserted into tables with Consistency Level(CL) quorum.
node1 -- 11.21.1.26
node2 -- 11.21.1.27
node3 -- 11.21.1.28

In the above configuration, I understand that all nodes have all data.

During one of the maintenance window, node 2 was down.

```
$nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
=======================**
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns  Host ID    RACK
DN  11.21.1.27  13.43 GiB  256     ?     aaaa      rack1
UN  11.21.1.26  13.85 GiB  256     ?     bbbb      rack1
UN  11.21.1.28  13.65 GiB  256     ?     cccc      rack1
```

```
Using cqlsh on node1(11.21.1.26), consistency set to quorum, When tried to read data for the table1, data is queried successfully.

Using cqlsh on node3(11.21.1.28), consistency set to quorum, When tried to read same data from node3(11.21.1.28), reads are getting failed.
Unable to fetch query trace: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {<Host: 11.21.1.28 DC1>: Unavailable('Error from server: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM" info={\'required_replicas\': 1, \'alive_replicas\': 0, \'consistency\': \'QUORUM\'}',)})
```

Can any one explain why queries from node3(11.21.1.28) are failing, even though only node2(11.21.1.27) was down. Two other nodes are up and running.

I was expecting the query to work from node3 and node1, since node1 and node3 are up.

Comment: Please read the `cassandra` tag.

Comment: Should probably be moved to the `cassandra` tag on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So I read this:

> We have 3 node cluster with Replication factor 3.

But this part of the error message conflicts with that statement:

```
Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"
    info={\''required_replicas\': 1, \'alive_replicas\': 0,
```

If the RF really was 3, then the `required_replicas` for QUORUM would be 2, not 1.

So here's why QUORUM can be tricky. Remember that QUORUM is computed as (RF / 2) + 1. My guess is that the replication factor on the keyspace is 1.

QUORUM of RF==1 : (1 / 2) == 0; 0 + 1 == 1

With a RF of 1, the data rows do not have any additional replicas. Therefore, with one node in a down state, there is roughly 1/3 of the data which cannot be queried.

I would double-check the keyspace definition, because it doesn't appear to be set with a RF of 3.